# Is there a way to assign conditional methods or add preprosessor directives at run-time in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, runtime, c-preprocessor

The aim is to be able to switch debugging calls on at run-time from database on a production build ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the point of conditional methods and preprocessor directives is that they cause the compiler to omit code from the final executable. The runtime equivalent of these is an `if` statement.

However, [aspect-orientated programming](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.NET+AOP&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) is roughly equivalent to what you're asking, in that it allows you to inject code into a running program that wouldn't otherwise be there.

**Edit:** as Joe mentioned, the way to do this is to program against a logging framework like log4net that allows fine-grained control over what gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

Not at the pre-processor level. After all, you're running the result of that process. Of course, you could change your pre-processor checks to be normal code checks, which can obviously be switched as required.

Answer (score 1):

No, but most logging subsystems provide this ability.  E.g. with log4net you can change the logging level dynamically, or if using System.Diagnostics.Trace you can change the [TraceSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.traceswitch(VS.71).aspx) level dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can't affect the binary code as such (as with the #if statement).

What I usually do is to make sure that my code contains a lot of logging, that is activated by [trace switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.traceswitch.aspx). That way you can have a system run in production with little or no logging, and when you want to research some problem you can switch logging on by altering the config file.